# wpf datagrid concept? committed?

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I am doing battle with a WPF DATAGRID.
[This grid contains a column into which I would like the user to enter some numbers. I would like to capture those number as they are entered, validate them, save them in a db & populate another (readonly) column based the input value.
I am at the capture stage of this little development.]

This page ...

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/communitytoolkit/controls/datagrid_guidance/editing_inputvalidation

... contains this statement ...

"A cell-level edit is committed when you move to another cell in the same row."

What does "committed" mean in this context?

When I make the object that feeds my grid rows IEditableObject I see the BeginEdit & EndEdit being called twice each time I hit [enter] (only one column is editable). Since these methods have no parameters how do I identify the row I'm dealing with & and access the data entered?
Are BeginningEdit, CellEditEnding & RowEditEnding required as well?

I created a test app based on
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.ieditableobject?view=net-5.0
&
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.ibindinglist?view=net-5.0

I added two integers, score & points to the customer. I set all  fields except points to read-only & where Score is set I set Points also.
When I ran it, I expected to see Points displayed. No joy.

When I changed !inTxn to inTxn in the following, bingo!

```
    private void OnCustomerChanged()
    {
        if (inTxn && Parent != null)
        {
            Parent.CustomerChanged(this);
        }
    }
```

Is this valid behaviour?
Is the documentation correct or incorrect?

Well my joy was short lived. Added some validation & the Points field stopped showing. Seriously. Backed that out & no recovery.

Answer (score 1):

It means to make permanent. An edit-in-progress can either be committed or rolled back. A cell edit is made permanent to its data source when you move to another cell in the same row. It goes on to say you must implement `IEditableObject` to handle edits properly.